# SQL - why i get 0 instead of blank after impoting csv file?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

This is my csv file: ind.csv:

```
RS0001000108;5;;;;;71.2;223.0;-6.1;;;
```

i have a some blank values (between ;;)

After importing my csv file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'files/ind.csv' INTO TABLE afcweb.abl_ind FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

in the table afcweb.abl_ind i see 0 instead of blank values.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Column has a default value?

Comment: default value = NULL

Comment: A space is not `NULL`, so it is translated into a number.  Hence the `0`.

Comment: even i set null instead of blank like this `RS0001000108;5;null;null;null;null;71.2;223.0;-6.1;null;null;` i got a 0

Comment: check the definition of table afcweb.abl_ind, it may have a default value as 0

Comment: i have checked it, the default value is NULL and not 0

Comment: What is the data type of your columns?

Comment: The data type is FLOAT